# Cipher suites: same name, different IDs, why?

Tags: tls, ciphersuite

Sorry if I missed with a community to ask.

Recently I stumbled on a fact that the same cipher suite can be designated by two different IDs, and this is not a typo nor single occasion.

For instance:
http://www.thesprawl.org/research/tls-and-ssl-cipher-suites

- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA is `0x0047` and `0xC001`
- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA is `0x0048` and `0xC002`
- SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA is `0xFEFE` and `0xFFE1`
- SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA is `0xFEFF` and `0xFFE0`

And few others more, like TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA and TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.

So, the question is: why two codes are used to designate the same cipher suite? Is it a marker of legacy (broken?) implementation to distinguish? Or just a merge of two standards? Or something else?

Comment: TLS fingerprints. [0x0047](https://tlsfingerprint.io/find/cipher/0047) 0%, [0xc001](https://tlsfingerprint.io/find/cipher/c001) 0.07%

Comment: Only [pocketbeat](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/packetbeat/protos/tls/algos.go) uses 0x0047 and it is belong to [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/ciphers.html) and all your first numbers belongs to them. Here a list from [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.gska100/csdcwh.htm)

Comment: It should be noted that all 4 of those examples are deprecated and should not be used

Comment: The official registry is https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4 . All of your first numbers are unregistered and in violation of the standard. C001,C002 are standard but insecure and hence unpopular. FFxx are nonstandard but permitted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These numbers belong to [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/ciphers.html);

- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA is `0x0047`
- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA is `0x0048`
- SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA is `0xFEFE`
- SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA is `0xFEFF`

and `0x0047` has almost 0% at [tlsfingerprint.io](https://tlsfingerprint.io/find/cipher/0047)

The second numbers in SSL/TLS in this format `{0xC0,0x01},{0xC0,0x01},{0xFF,0xE1},{0xFF,0xE0}`. The first two in [rfc4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-6). These are deprecated in [rfc8422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8422#page-33). The last two is for private usage.

The implementations can have different control by the maintainers, therefore it is good to have different numbers. It is bad that your original source doesn't list where they took the numbers.

---

**Note:** in TLS 1.3, there are only [5 cipher suites](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28#page-131) with their id's;

- `{0x13,0x01}` - TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- `{0x13,0x02}` - TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
- `{0x13,0x03}` - TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- `{0x13,0x04}` - TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256
- `{0x13,0x05}` - TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256

Comment: So, am I correct this is just a merge of two standards, Elastic and SSL?

Comment: @YurySchkatula They just merge some lists, maybe contains more than two, as BearSLL/TLS... One has to look at all.

Comment: C001 and C002 are in rfc4492 which applies to TLS 1.0 and 1.1 and was carried forward to TLS 1.2 with some modifications (Appendix A.7 of rfc5246), but deleted by rfc8422 in 2018-08 shortly before this A. FFE0 and FFE1 were and are 'private use' for TLS only, and not mentioned on the page you link. Neither is related to SSLv2 at all; SSLv2 ciphersuites were _three_ octets and those obviously arent.

Comment: First two 'code' lines in [section 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4492#section-6). Although often treated as a 16-bit bigendian number, SSL/TLS actually defines CipherSuite as two 8-bit bytes, see e.g. rfc5246 section A.4.1 and A.5. (And https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4 .)